# DynamoDB column value reset to its initial value everyday

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table called 'Alunos' and one column called 'Presente' and it's a boolean value, which is set 'true'. And if a student didn't attend class, it changes to 'false'.
I need to know, how to make this value return 'true' automatically when changed the day. 
Example: today is 9/10/19 and the value of the column is false. When it changes the day - 10/10/19 - it should return true. (its initial value)
How could I do that? Any tips?

Also, after doing that, I want to create a report or dashboard about this data, a monthly report for example. Do you have any tip for it as well?

Hope I made me clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change any existring value. 
Here is what you should do.

1. Create 1 entry for everyday, with default value set to true or false.
2. Change the value based on user attendance.
3. Use enum instead of true/false.

This will make sure

1. You can see past trend.
2. you can have complex pattern like if holiday have new value than true and false.

---

If you are adamant on using single value per user, have a lambda function triggered by cloudwatch event everyday, which resets the value. But it will cause significant number of write everyday, instead of doing that you can check if value is expired and update only if expired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So, the solution I found out created another table just to save the date and the ID of the student who isn't present to class..
Now my challenge is to generate a report based on this table. This one I don't have an idea yet.. If you have any concern, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

this can solve your problem:

> Time to Live (TTL) for Amazon DynamoDB lets you define when items in a table expire so that they can be automatically deleted from the database. TTL is provided at no extra cost as a way to reduce storage usage and reduce the cost of storing irrelevant data without using provisioned throughput.

and here is an example [to set up TTL](https://jun711.github.io/aws/how-to-set-ttl-for-amazon-dynamodb-entries/)